# Subgrid with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I know how to get a grid in `pgfplots` as shown below, but how can I get  additionally a subgrid without labels?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[grid=both,no markers,samples=100]
      \addplot {sin(deg(x))};
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `grid=both` and `minor tick num=<number>`; then (if you want to) you can set the length for the minor ticks to `0pt`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
  grid=both,
  no markers,
  samples=100,
  minor tick num=2,
  every minor tick/.style={minor tick length=0pt}]
      \addplot {sin(deg(x))};
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]