# Mimic GeoGebra's grid lines with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, plot, ticks, geogebra

Using pgfplots, I want to have grid lines similar to [GeoGebra's](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator). That is four minor ticks in between major ticks and a lighter color for the minor grid lines:

[image: GeoGebra's grid lines]

With the help of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73936/subgrid-with-pgfplots), I managed to get this code

```
\documentclass[margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=center,
        grid=both,
        xtick distance=1,
        ytick distance=1,
        xmin=-3.5,
        xmax=3.5,
        ymin=-3.5,
        ymax=3.5,
        x=1cm,
        y=1cm,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        xlabel style={right},
        ylabel style={above},
        minor tick num=4,
        every minor tick/.style={minor tick length=0pt}
    ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following result:

[image: pgfplots' grid]

However, this still doesn't quite look like the grid lines from GeoGebra. Is there a way to have separate colors for the major and minor grid lines?

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: In the p.372, with         major grid style={gray},
        minor grid style={gray!50}

Comment: @pascal974 Yes, that works. Many thanks! I'm not sure if I can mark this post as solved with only a comment and no real answer.

Comment: I post an answer and offer an alternative with tkz-base

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the doc p.372 With `major grid style={gray}, minor grid style={gray!50}`

```
\documentclass[margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=center,
        grid=both,
        xtick distance=1,
        ytick distance=1,
        xmin=-3.5,
        xmax=3.5,
        ymin=-3.5,
        ymax=3.5,
        x=1cm,
        y=1cm,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        xlabel style={right},
        ylabel style={above},
        minor tick num=4,
        every minor tick/.style={minor tick length=0pt},
        %%%
        major grid style={gray}, minor grid style={gray!50}%<-- added
    ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

An alternative with the package `tkz-base`

```
\documentclass[margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-base}
\begin{document}
\def\tkzCoeffSubColor{20}% instead of 50
\def\tkzCoeffSubLw{0.2}% instead of 0.75
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[
    xmin=-3.5,
    xmax=3.5,
    ymin=-3.5,
    ymax=3.5,
]
% we can change the step for the second grid
\tkzGrid[sub,color=orange,
subxstep=.2,subystep=.2]
\tkzAxeXY
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]